RCBO and neutral wire
If I take the output neutral wire of the RCBO and touch it to the grounded wire, the output phase wire does not touch anything, the RCBO will cut off the power.
The reason for this could be that there is a current from the ground going into the neutral wire; it creates a current difference between the phase wire and the neutral wire, causing the RCBO to cut off the power, right?

Yes.
Although the direction of the current is both ways or either way, from neutral to ground or ground to neutral, because it's an AC system.
Even without load on the RCBO/GFCI downstream output, if you connect a downstream Neutral wire to Earth/Ground wire, it will form a parallel path for upstream Neutral wire current to flow also partially through the RCBO/GFCI to the place where Neutral wires are bonded to Earth/Ground wires.

Not sure how that answers the question.

@DrMoishePippik The question is a statement about how RCBO works and asks if the statement is correct. Connecting Neutral to Earth causes imbalance between Neutral and Live which the RCBO detects and cuts off.

RCBOs work by monitoring the difference in current between the conductors going through its current transformer. If there is an imbalance greater than the trip value then the circuit breaker opens.
Any connection between neutral and earth bonding will cause the current to split to alternate paths back to the local transformer. This will cause an imbalance at the RBCO and it will trip.

If I take the output neutral wire of the RCBO and touch it to the grounded wire, the output phase wire does not touch anything, the RCBO will cut off the power.

Yes, provided you do this on the load side of the RCBO and not the incoming supply.

The reason for this could be that there is a current from the ground going into the neutral wire;

Although we're dealing with AC here, it is convention to say that current is supplied by the live, L, and returns to source by the neutral, N. Continuing that logic in the situation you have described, we would say, "The current from the neutral goes into the ground and returns to the source (usually the local transformer)."

... it creates a current difference between the phase wire and the neutral wire, causing the RCBO to cut off the power, right?

Correct.

A RCBO (GFCI) detects any current in the Ground (G, or Earth) wire, i.e., any imbalance between currents in Line (L) and Neutral (N), over a few mA and opens the circuit, to avoid electric shock to a living being.
In normal operation, the N wires carries current from all devices on that circuit, so there is a small voltage drop along the N wire. The G wire normally does not carry significant current, so there is negligible voltage drop. Connecting the two causes current to flow between N and G -- though the N connection might be only a fraction of a volt from G, there's still ample current through low-impedance house wiring to trip that safety device.

"A RCBO (GFCI) detects any current in the Ground (G, or Earth) wire, ..." That's not quite the correct wording, is it? The RCBO knows nothing about ground / earth wires or whether they're there or not so it is unable to detect any current in it. I know you understand how they work - it's just not worded well.

No it doesn't detect current of earth/ground wire. It simply detects if there is equal amount of current flowing on Live and the returning Neutral wire. If not, it leaks somewhere, but not necessarily through the RCBO/GFCI ground wire, but elsewhere. Even if there would be a negligible voltage drop, if say 1A flows in the neutral before GFCI, and you connect Neutral and Ground together after GFCI, you might assume 500mA flows per wire, GFCI trips.
